# How to call a HTML page from any page after a given time?

Tags: php, html

I want to call a PHP page which contains many html tags after a given time later such as 1  mins 2 mins etc. If I use header then it works for one time. When it find an html tag then it  does not work for second time. But I want to call the page until i go to offline. Please  anyone help me.....

Comment: Could you be more proper in your question ?

Comment: Give us an example of what you tried so far and I would advise to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're talking about:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='60'/>
</head>
```

This will cause the page to be reloaded every 60 seconds.